# Динамическое добавление полей форме с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, форма

Всем привет! Задача кажется тривиальной, но оказалось все не так просто:
У меня есть форма, к форме привязан fieldset, и в него я складываю поля следующей верстки:

```
<fieldset id="fset" form="data">
<?php foreach($fields as $field):?>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label"><?php echo $fRel[$field->getType()] ?></label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="s[<?php echo $field->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $field->getName();?>">
<input type="button" ref="<?php echo $field->getId() ?>" value="Удалить поле" class="btn btn-primary deleteButton"/>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</fieldset>
```

И потом в жизненном цикле я добавляю подобную конструкцию следующим образом:
    $('#fset').append(template);

template - это идентичный приведенному код, но сформированный в JavaScript.
Однако при отправке формы введенные в новые поля данные теряются. Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: @SoWa, не забывайте отмечать принятый ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял исходные данные, то при отправке формы, как правило, происходит перезагрузка страницы. Поэтому динамически добавленные поля  и пропадают.

Можно отправлять данные формы асинхронно, не уходя со страницы. Или же сохранять факт добавления пользователем полей на стороне сервера (в сессии, например) и при повторной загрузке страницу выдавать уже с ними.

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться, но значение в appand разве не должно быть в одну строку?

То есть:

```
$('#fset').append('<fieldset id="fset" form="data">'
 + '<?php foreach($fields as $field):?>' 
 + '<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label">');
```

и т.д.

Значение в template попробуйте записать без переносов строк.

Comment: Ну кавычки ещё конечно же, если непосредственно в appand вставлять =)

Comment: @mccrush, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: template формируется правильно, а проблема была действительно в перезагрузке формы. Пока поставил костыль вида: "fieldset.append(template); form.submit()", тогда происходит отправка формы с пустым полем, страница перезагружается и отображает форму уже с ним.